# Google maps set null as default when open markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, geojson, gmaps.js

is there a way to create 'set map (null)' as the default when the map is opened? I mean when I first open a web page, all data on the map does not appear.

i call data using database and load data geojson from my storage

```
<?php foreach ($map_link->result_array() as $i) : ?>
  var <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?> = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
  <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>.loadGeoJson('<?= base_url().'/asset/mapgeojson/geojson/'.$i['maplink_url']; ?>');
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php foreach ($map_link->result_array() as $i) : ?>
  $('#<?= $i['maplink_var'];?>').click(function(){
    <?= $i['maplink_var'];?>.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
  });
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this my javascript for on off button and show hide map

```
$('#jalan_nasional,#jalan_provinsi,#air_bersih,#bendung,#jembatan,#sanitasi,#pelabuhan,#terminal,#stasiun,#bandara,#sungai,#sungaipol,#tol').removeAttr('disabled');

    $('#all').click(function(){
      <?php foreach ($map_link->result_array() as $i) : ?>
        <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
        tol.setMap($(this).is(':checked') ? map : null);
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#all').click(function() {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
      });
    })
```

and this is my button for on off data

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        All
        <div class="material-switch pull-right">
          <input id="all" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="all" class="label-success"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="checkboxes">

        <ul class="list-group">

          <li class="list-group-item">
            Jalan Nasional
            <div class="material-switch pull-right">
              <input id="jalan_nasional" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
              <label for="jalan_nasional" class="label-success"></label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Jalan Provinsi
            <div class="material-switch pull-right">
              <input id="jalan_provinsi" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
              <label for="jalan_provinsi" class="label-success"></label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Air
            <div class="material-switch pull-right">
              <input id="air_bersih" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
              <label for="air_bersih" class="label-success"></label>
            </div>
          </li>
```

there's actually nothing wrong with my code. at first when I open a web page, all data is called all so that the screen is full with marker data by default.
and the button functions to hide and display the marker.
And for the current problem, I want to make map data by default not appear when the web page is first opened and all buttons are in the off position.

maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Then in your initial assignement  set null each marker ( instead of a valid map value)

```
    <?php foreach ($map_link->result_array() as $i) : ?>
      $('#<?= $i['maplink_var'];?>').click(function(){
        <?= $i['maplink_var'];?>.setMap( null);
      });
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```